# how to get values of object list using for loop in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of object type in c#. Now I want to get values of each element using for loop . I have searched a lot on web but I always found only foreach loop method.

Comment: What is your exact question ?

Comment: What is wrong with the `foreach` approach?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please add some source code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: my question is i have a list (List<point> li=new List<point>(); where point is a class and it has two attributes xcor and ycor ) now i want fetch the values of these attributes using for loop. In java we can use something like li.get(index).getxcor(); but in c# i haven't find any such method

Comment: You can get your object by using point p = li[i];

Comment: I suggest you read an introductory tutorial to .NET collections. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx is a start...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over a list using `for` like shown below, although using `foreach` is generally cleaner

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    var xcor = list[i].xcor;
    var ycor = list[i].ycor;
}
```

The equivalent `foreach` loop would look like this:

```
foreach (var point in list)
{
   var xcor = point.xcor;
   var ycor = point.ycor
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would get each `object` in a list of `objects` with a `for` loop

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
 {
      SomeMethodThatDoesSomethingWithAnObject(list[i]);
 }
```

Comment: this would just iterate over the collection and pass the loop counter to the method.  Did you mean to pass `list[i]` as the argument?  I would also use a foreach over a for loop, however this is just preference.

Comment: yes I did.  Thanks for catching that. I edited my post.